# realmdb swift not reading values from file

Tags: ios, swift, database, mobile, realm

I've been using RealmDB in a project I've been working on. I'm trying to fetch a logged in user in `AppDelegate.swift` from the DB with the following query.

`let result = self.realm.objects(AuthModel.self).filter("isLoggedIn == true").first`

I know that this user exists because I've opened up the realm file and seen the field

[image: realmdb item where logged in is true]

However, when I make this realm call, I get the following response

`[0] AuthModel {
        ...
        userID = (null);
        isLoggedIn = 0;
    }
)`

It seems to be returning a default value in which user id is null and is logged in is false (or 0). Why would this be happening? Is there any kind of setup I need to do to call this method?

Comment: How did you get the response? From debugger or did you print it in code? I wouldn't rely on debugger as Realm objects are lazily loaded so they get values at the moment they are accessed.

Comment: I used a print statement in the code

Comment: Directly on the `authModel.isLoggedIn` property or just like `print(authModel)`?

Comment: The code was print(result)

Comment: So if you try `print(result.isLoggedIn)` it is still `false`?

Comment: Yeah, it is still `fasle`